# Pyautogui: I have to move the mouse manually for pyautogui to click

Tags: python, pyautogui

**NOTE:** My problem isn't that it doesn't click, my problem is that it **only** clicks once I *manually move the mouse*

I'm using the python library 'pyautogui', and when I run code like this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    cash = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('cash.png',confidence=0.8)
    if cash != None:
        pyautogui.click(cash)
```

**It finds what it is looking for**, but doesn't click on it **until I move the mouse manually.**

This happens every time I try pyautogui.

Comment: I tried running your code using PyCharm 2020.3 with Python 3.9 on Windows 10 and it works fine. Try adding `time.sleep(1)` after `pyautogui.click(cash)`, I'm thinking maybe the program clicks too often within a second?

Comment: As a side note, `pyautogui.FAILSAFE` by default is `True` so you don't need that line

Comment: @AndrewStone I know that the failsafe is on by default, I just wanted to be sure, and it works!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i would do is instead of going

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    cash = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('cash.png',confidence=0.8)
    if cash != None:
        pyautogui.click(cash)
```

you would do

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    cash = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('cash.png',confidence=0.8)
    if cash != None:
    pyautogui.move(cash)
        pyautogui.click(cash)
```

your problem is that the program is just going to run click but it doesnt know to actually move there and THAN click.

Answer (score 1):

Pyautogui seemed to be sending too many requests for the mouse to handle, so slowing it down by adding a time.sleep(1) did the trick.

I don't know if anyone else had this problem, but I am glad for it to be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

That may happen because you haven't inserted the co-ordinates in your "click()" function. If you don't insert the co-ordinates, python will click where the mouse pointer's location is. If you insert co-ordinates like "click(12, 35)", then python will click on the specific co-ordinates you enter. You can get the co-ordinates of your screen by any image editor like paint

Comment: You explain the situation but not a solution.

Comment: See, if you type only click(), then python will click where your mouse pointer is located. But if you tell python to click on a certain x co-ordinate and y co-ordinate like click((x position)12, (y position)35), then python  will click on the position marking you entered. If you still have doubts, please ask

Comment: Let's take a look in your code:

`import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    cash = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('cash.png',confidence=0.8)
    if cash != None:
        pyautogui.click(cash)`

So, instead of going there, you can open `cash.png` in paint, get the xy co-ordinates in the photo editor and paste it in the `click()` function like this:

`import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    cash = "Your x co-ordinates", "Your y co-ordinates"
    if cash != None:
        pyautogui.click(cash)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pyautogui

>>> screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size() # Get the size of the primary monitor.

>>> currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position() # Get the XY position of the mouse.

>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.

>>> pyautogui.click()          # Click the mouse.
>>> pyautogui.click(100, 200)  # Move the mouse to XY coordinates and click it.
>>> pyautogui.click('button.png') # Find where button.png appears on the screen and click it.

>>> pyautogui.move(0, 10)      # Move mouse 10 pixels down from its current position.
>>> pyautogui.doubleClick()    # Double click the mouse.
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(500, 500, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)  # Use tweening/easing function to move mouse over 2 seconds.

>>> pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)  # type with quarter-second pause in between each key
>>> pyautogui.press('esc')     # Press the Esc key. All key names are in pyautogui.KEY_NAMES

>>> pyautogui.keyDown('shift') # Press the Shift key down and hold it.
>>> pyautogui.press(['left', 'left', 'left', 'left']) # Press the left arrow key 4 times.
>>> pyautogui.keyUp('shift')   # Let go of the Shift key.

>>> pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') # Press the Ctrl-C hotkey combination.

>>> pyautogui.alert('This is the message to display.') # Make an alert box appear and pause the program until OK is clicked.
```

**In your case use** `pyautogui.click(100, 200)  # Move the mouse to XY`